# Simple mod_rewrite rule for adding /

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an URL http://domain.com/test/main/getbts?_dc=13 and would like to add a / before the ?-mark in order for the URL to look:  https://domain.net/test/main/getbts/?_dc=13

I tried the following Rewrite Rule:

```
RewriteRule ^test/main/getbts/\?_dc\=([^/]*)$ /test/main/getbts?_dc=$1 [L]
```

But it does not seem to work. My other rewrite rules (*I have not used at the time I tested my first rule*) are:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Could anyone give me a hint where to look or how to rewrite my rules?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a `RewriteRule`, just the URI. And in this case, you can just ignore it since it'll automatically get appended to the end. You just need:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/main/getcbts$ /admin/main/getcbts/ [L,R=301]
```

This redirects the browser so they see a `/` at the end of the URI in the location bar.